# How do I get rid of these broken package errors and install Mate in Linux Mint 16 Petra?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, mate-desktop

I have upgraded my computer to Linux Mint 16 Petra. Everything worked smoothly during the install with no errors, or indications of any problems.

However, after I rebooted, Mate was no longer an option among all the sessions. I have Cinnamon and Gnome, but no Mate.

I logged in using Cinnamon and tried to install Mate using Synaptic, but it keeps giving me errors about broken packages.

How do I install Mate in Linux Mint 16 Petra?

Here is some output that I hope will be helpful in determining the problem:

```
homebase ~ # sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-desktop-environment : Depends: mate-core (= 1.6.0.1+raring) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: mate-screensaver (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: mate-applets (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
homebase ~ # apt-get install mate-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-core : Depends: libmatekbd (>= 1.6.0)
             Depends: libmatewnck (>= 1.6.0)
             Depends: libmatedesktop (>= 1.6.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
homebase ~ # apt-get install libmatekbd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mate-settings-daemon : Depends: mate-settings-daemon-gstreamer (>= 1.6.1-1~mate1+petra) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 mate-settings-daemon-pulse (>= 1.6.1-1~mate1+petra) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: The first thing to try is `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for responding. I tried those commands, but they didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Use *Synaptic* to remove any and all *MATE* related packages. Anything
   with *MATE* in the name.
2. Change the repositories to the defaults using the software sources
   interface. For some reason, *Synaptic* would not open that interface,
   so I used the *Update Manager* instead.
3. Update the package information.
4. Install `mint-meta-mate`.
5. Logout, and log back in using *MATE*.

All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

Using aptitude for package management instead of apt-get, please note that it is bad practice to use aptitude and apt-get interchangeably, as they record separately the changes made by a user.

Open the Terminal from the Mint Menu and start with the commands:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install gtkorphan
```

Continue by running:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade
```

This is used to double-check that you have all the updates.

To clear out the broken packages use the command:

```
sudo aptitude -f
```

Please goto the following link for more info https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/482

Comment: You write that it's « _bad practice to use aptitude and apt-get interchangeably, as they record separately the changes made by a user_ ». Are you sure about this? I've never encountered issues, and I can't find anything online that agrees with your warning. The closest I can find is that `aptitude` manages the automatic removal of dependencies, whereas `apt-get` requires an explicit action to do so.